# Gradle Plugin Dependency tree

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

Is there way that I can see the plugin dependency tree?

I keep running into issues with plugins that were brought in via transitive dependency with another plugin.   Apparently, I now have 'org.jfrog.artifactory' plugin in my project and no idea what brought it in.   Yesterday, it was the GraalVM plugin.

Comment: Did you try [googling it](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html)?

Comment: Of course.  There are dependency trees for jars, but nothing about the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this to see the dependency trees of plugins:

```bash
./gradlew -i buildEnvironment
```

I tried this with Gradle 8, and it worked correctly. The `buildEnvironment` task has been around for a while, so I assume that it will work for older versions of Gradle as well.